# Passing data in PageViewControllers swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I have a page controller where I added UIViewControllers and display a bunch of form in each viewcontroller. The issue I am facing now is that I need to get the data supplied in each of the forms and save it which is done in the last view controller. I have tried using delegates but the moment the next button is clicked, the previous value stored becomes `nil` and only the value of the latest `VC` is displayed. How can I pass data in this textfields. Any help is appritated.

My delegate

```
protocol NextDelegate: AnyObject {
    func next(pageIndex: Int, model: CreatePropertyModel)
    func previous(pageIndex: Int, model: CreatePropertyModel)
}
```

how I created array of VC

```
lazy var controllers: [UIViewController] = {
        let descVC = DescVC()
        descVC.delegate = self
        let priceVC = PriceVC()
        priceVC.delegate = self
        let featuresVC = FeaturesVC()
        featuresVC.delegate = self
        let picturesVC = PicturesVC()
        picturesVC.delegate = self
        return [descVC, priceVC, featuresVC, picturesVC]
    }()
```

Model Example

```
class CreatePropertyModel: DictionaryEncodable {
    var title: String?
    var desc: String?
    var property_type_id: Int?
    var property_sub_type_id: Int?
    var location_id: Int?
    var currency: String?
    var price: Int?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all your steps, store it in a singleton.

```swift
protocol Answer {
    var isDone: Bool { get }
}

class Answer1: Answer {
    static public let updatedNotification = Notification.Name("Answer1Updated")

    var name: String? {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Answer1.updatedNotification, object: nil)
        }
    }

    var isDone: Bool {
        return name != nil
    }
}

class Answer2: Answer {
    var age: Int?

    var isDone: Bool {
        return age != nil
    }
}

class Form {
    static let shared = Form()

    var answers: [Answer] = [Answer1(), Answer2()]

    var isDone: Bool {
        return answers.allSatisfy { $0.isDone == true }
    }

    private init() {}

    func reset() {
        answers = [Answer1(), Answer2()]
    }

    var answer1: Answer1? {
        return Form.shared.answers.filter { $0 is Answer1 }.first as? Answer1
    }

    var answer2: Answer2? {
        return Form.shared.answers.filter { $0 is Answer2 }.first as? Answer2
    }
}
```

Then, in your view controller, read / write values like this.

```swift
class MyViewControllerForAnswer1: UIViewController {
    var answer: Answer1? {
        return Form.shared.answer1
    }

    var name: String? {
        get {
            return answer?.name
        }
        set {
            answer?.name = newValue
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(answerUpdated(notification:)), name: Answer1.updatedNotification, object: nil)

    }

    @objc func answerUpdated(notification: Notification) {
        // Update your content
    }
}
```

Comment: `Answer1` and `Answer2` are viewcontrollers?

Comment: I added model example

Comment: `MyViewControllerForAnswer1` is the view controller for `Answer1` model

Comment: I have a next Button on the ParentVC which triggers next